# maven-failsafe-plugin: how to pass option to JUnit?

Tags: maven, junit, maven-failsafe-plugin

I use [`maven-failsafe-plugin`](http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-failsafe-plugin) to run my integration tests. When it fails, I see full stack trace. For each failed test case it may has about ~50 lines, most of which are related to Junit. I found that Junit has [`filtertrace`](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/junit.html) option which allows to strip part of stack trace, but I cannot figure out how to pass this option to Junit?

Also I tried `trimStackTrace` option of `maven-failsafe-plugin` but it doesn't changed output of failed tests.

Is it possible to pass `filtertrace` option from plugin to Junit? (without using `maven-antrun-plugin` or similar plugins.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`maven-failsafe-plugin` (and `maven-surefire-plugin`) contains [bug when `trimStackTrace` has no effect on JUnit 4.x](https://jira.codehaus.org/browse/SUREFIRE-935) It fixed in version 2.13, so in my case i should update plugin to newer version.

Answer (score 1):

The first thing is which version of the failsafe-plugin and JUnit do you use? How did you try to configure the trimStackTrace Option, because the trimStackTrace option is true by default.

```
<plugins>
   <plugin>
      <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
      <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>2.9</version>
      <configuration>
         <trimStackTrace>true</trimStackTrace>
      </configuration>
   </plugin>
</plugins>
```

Have you tried to configure the systemPropertiesFile to pass the filtertrace to JUnit.

Comment: I use junit 4.8.2 Before your answer I used `maven-failsafe-plugin` without specifying version because I expected that maven will use latest version (and it was my mistake). But now I specified it explicitly, as in your example, but nothing changed. By the way, I think `trimStackTrace` option for another purpose: if stack trace has many exceptions which chained with each others, then it shows only one exception. Isn't it? I don't try `systemPropertiesFile` but I try `systemPropertyVariables` and it doesn't helped because it passes properties to Junit's tests, not to Junit.